# cmake with vcpkg can't find *.lib files

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I want to use DirectXTK via vcpkg and link it with my cmake project.

`vcpkg.exe list` shows the following:

```
directxtk:x86-windows                              apr2021          A collection of helper classes for writing Direc...
directxtk:x86-windows-static-md                    apr2021          A collection of helper classes for writing Direc...
libzip:x86-windows                                 1.7.3#2          A library for reading, creating, and modifying z...
libzip:x86-windows-static-md                       1.7.3#2          A library for reading, creating, and modifying z...
zlib:x86-windows                                   1.2.11#10        A compression library
zlib:x86-windows-static-md                         1.2.11#10        A compression library
```

[dependnencies from these are not included here]

You can see that DirectXTK,libzip and zlib is installed.

Now my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Game PRIVATE ZLIB::ZLIB)
if(WIN32)
    find_package(directxtk CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(Game PRIVATE DirectXTK)
endif()
find_package(libzip REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Game PRIVATE libzip)
```

When I try to compile my project, it says

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'DirectXTK.lib'
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libzip.lib'
```

It can't find the lib files for `DirectXTK` and `libzip` when linking.
It compiles fine though, which means it **can** find `zlib.h` and `DirectXTK/WICTextureLoader` for example.

How am I supposed to fix that?
The cmake Toolchain is correctly set to `vcpkg.cmake` and I used `vcpkg.exe integrate install` prior.

Comment: [DirectXTK wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK#cmake) tells that linking with the library is performed via `Microsoft::DirectXTK` target but you link with `DirectXTK` instead.

Comment: As for libzip library, its configuration is [installed](https://github.com/nih-at/libzip/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L445) with NAMESPACE option equal to `libzip::`, so the proper target to link with is `libzip::zip` (not a `libzip` as in your code).

Comment: @Tsyvarev When I use `target_link_libraries(Game PRIVATE Microsoft::DirectXTK)` I receive this error:
`Target "Game" links to target "Microsoft::DirectXMath" but the target was
not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
`

Comment: I fixed it by installing DirectXMath and adding `find_packages(directxmath)`, too.
Can you make an answer out of your comments? @Tsyvarev